# How to use R's native pipe and placeholder in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I use the native pipe and placeholder inside a ggplot geom?

When passing a data.frame to ggplot the native pipe works fine, but inside a geom I need to use the 'magrittr' pipe when I want to filter the original data.frame.

So this works fine:

```
mtcars |> 
     ggplot() +
     geom_col(data = . %>% filter(cyl == 4),
              aes(x = gear, y = mpg),
              fill = "grey80") +
     geom_text(data = . %>% filter(cyl == 4 & gear == 3),
               aes(x = gear,
                   y = mpg,
                   label = "ooo"), color = "tomato3") +
     theme_minimal()
```

With an anonymous function, I can switch completely to the native pipe:

```
mtcars |> 
     ggplot() +
     geom_col(data = (\(x) filter(x, cyl == 4)),
              aes(x = gear, y = mpg),
              fill = "grey80") +
     geom_text(data = (\(x) filter(x, cyl == 4 & gear == 3)),
               aes(x = gear,
                   y = mpg,
                   label = "ooo"), color = "tomato3") +
     theme_minimal()
```

But is there an elegant way to use R's native pipe operator AND the placeholder to do the same operation?

This throws the error 'invalid use of pipe placeholder':

```
mtcars |> 
     ggplot() +
     geom_col(data = _ |>  filter(cyl == 4),
              aes(x = gear, y = mpg),
              fill = "grey80") +
     geom_text(data = _ |>  filter(cyl == 4 & gear == 3),
               aes(x = gear,
                   y = mpg,
                   label = "ooo"), color = "tomato3") +
     theme_minimal()
```

Comment: native pipe placeholder is a new feature that was introduced in R 4.2. ggplot was already mature at this point. This is an issue with native R and has nothing to do with ggplot. I doubt ggplot will understand the parsing of `_|>`. I doubt whether there is backward compatibility with `_` placeholder. The best thing to do is stick with magrittr pipe

Comment: An option may be to use `mtcars` twice, so both in your `geom`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its possible to stay with the native pipe, but leverage that ggplot2 though perhaps deprecating formula syntax in favour of the new anonymous function syntax, still works.

```
mtcars |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = ~filter(., cyl == 4),
           aes(x = gear, y = mpg),
           fill = "grey80") +
  geom_text(data =  ~filter(., cyl == 4 & gear == 3),
            aes(x = gear,
                y = mpg,
                label = "ooo"), color = "tomato3") +
  theme_minimal()
```

That said, I personally am a great believer of not doing data manipulations in my plotting/charting code.
I would much rather do all my data changes up front, and then write a purely plotting function.

```
d1 <- filter(mtcars, cyl == 4)
d2 <- filter(mtcars, cyl == 4 & gear == 3)

  ggplot() +
  geom_col(data =  d1,
           aes(x = gear, y = mpg),
           fill = "grey80") +
  geom_text(data =  d2,
            aes(x = gear,
                y = mpg,
                label = "ooo"), color = "tomato3") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Thanks! Filtering and subsetting before plotting is probably the better workflow. I will stick to that in the future.

Answer (score 2):

##### In addition to the comments some considerations:

1. The placeholder `_` in the base pipe `|>` does refer to the first argument in the function that follows it.
2. The placeholder `.` in the magrittr pipe `%>%` refers to the data being piped.
3. In ggplot2 functions, the data argument does expect a data frame or similar object (e.g., tibble) and not a function call.
4. Therefore, you cannot use the base pipe and placeholder directly in the data argument.
5. But, you can use an anonymous function in the data argument, taking a data frame as input and using the base pipe and placeholder within this function.
6. Then you can apply a function to this data frame and return a data frame, which can be used directly by ggplot2.

Your second approach therefore works!